# Ignore Column Import in Laravel-Excel Maatwebsite

Tags: excel, laravel, import-from-excel, undefined-index

Can I ignore Excel columns import in Laravel-Excel Maatwebsite?

My example has a column A B C D E F G H.
But I have 4 different excel file types, namely:

- File 1, there is a column header A B C F G H
- File 2, there is a column header A B F G H
- File 3, there is a column header A B C D E F
- File 4, there is a column header A B C D E F G H

I've tried using WithHeadingRow in ExcelImport, but the response when I imported file 1 was ***Undefined index: header_D***.

in my ExcelController:

```
Excel::Import(new \App\Imports\ExcelImport,$request->file('file'));
        return redirect('/excel')->with("sukses","Data profiling berhasil di import");
```

in my ExcelImport:

```
class ProfilingImport implements ToCollection, WithChunkReading, WithCalculatedFormulas, WithHeadingRow
{
/**
* @param array $row
*
* @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
*/

use Importable;




public function collection(Collection $collection)
{
    $collection = $collection->toArray();

    

    foreach ($collection as $key => $row){
        if($key >= 2){
            

            return Profiling::create([
                'A' => $row['A'],
                'B' => $row['B'],
                'C' => $row['C'],
                'D' => $row['D'],
                'E' => $row['E'],
                'F' => $row['F'],
                'G' => $row['G'],
                'H' => $row['H'],
            ]);
            
        }
    }
```

File Excel:

```
| A | B | C | G | H |
|111|523|585|785|789|


| A | B | F | G | H |
|785|556|712|368|782|


| A | B | C | D | E | F |
|524|756|624|765|522|446|


| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H |
|123|456|789|012|345|678|901|234|
```

Comment: so what you want if header match then only import otherwise it will import null .?

Comment: Yes, totally correct. if the header in excel is not in the code then the result can be null, blank, zero, or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

it's based on doc it should work ref link https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/heading-row.html

```php
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\User;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;

class ProfilingImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow
{
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new Profiling([
            'A' => $row['A'] ?? null ,
            'B' => $row['B'] ?? null,
            'C' => $row['C'] ?? null,
            'D' => $row['D'] ?? null,
            'E' => $row['E'] ?? null,
            'F' => $row['F'] ?? null,
            'G' => $row['G'] ?? null,
            'H' => $row['H'] ?? null,
        ]);
    }

    public function headingRow(): int
    {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for answering, I keep using ToCollection and the result that column headers that are not in the excel file will be null.